# Windows API GUI - How do I call WM_COMMAND switch cases from within a function?

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface, winapi, window

I'm trying to create a GUI using the Windows API. Currently, I'm trying to make a function that runs when a button in the parent window is clicked on (button 1), which will delete other buttons in the window, create a text box for an input and a 'Confirm' button (button 2), and await for the user to click the confirm button.

When I press button 1, it calls input_function that is a method of a class which I created for another part of the program. Button 2, when pressed, it will take the text in the input box and pass it to a wchar_t variable "text" which I will then use in the another part of the program.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK ParentWindowProcedure(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp) {

    switch (msg) {
        case WM_COMMAND:
            switch(wp) {
                case INPUT: //button 1
                    MyList.input_function(hWnd, hSelectMatrix, hCreateNewMatrix);
                    break;
                case 5: //button 2
                    GetWindowTextW(hInputMatrixID, text, 100);
                    break;
```

```
void List::input_function(HWND handler1, HWND handler2, HWND handler3) { 

        text[0] = 'z';

        DestroyWindow(handler2); DestroyWindow(handler3); //Destroy other buttons in parent window when Button 1 is pressed
        
        hInputMatrixID = CreateWindowW(L"Edit", L"Input Matrix ID here...", WS_VISIBLE |      WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOHSCROLL | ES_AUTOVSCROLL, 1380, 70, 150, 50, handler1, NULL, NULL, NULL);

        hTemp = CreateWindowW(L"Button", L"Confirm ID", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 1380, 10, 150, 50, handler1, (HMENU)5, NULL, NULL);

//The idea here was to hold up the function until the user changes what is in "text"
        while(text[0] == 'z') { 
            continue;
        }
```

I'm still learning how to use the Windows API. I am struggling to understand how to have the program wait until the user presses button 2, or in other words, how do I make it so that I can call WM_COMMAND switch cases from within a function, and then resume the function afterwards?

I tried "holding up" the function with a while loop that continually checked if the text had been modified, obviously did not work since I assumed button 2 would be able to grab the text whenever.

Comment: A well behaved Windows program needs to continuously process messages so you can't "wait" if that means blocking that message loop. What you want to do instead is react to events, like `WM_COMMAND` messages when they happen. When the user clicks the confirm button you react to that and do what you need to do.

Comment: It seems you're essentially trying to create a modal dialog, without the dialog part. The Windows API does provide methods for modal windows (_e.g._ popups, menus, or `MessageBox`), and they basically run their own message loop, which is what stops the rest of your program from responding. You could probably do that here, although you should consider making an actual modal dialog instead, and call `DialogBox`.